# Unique Array Combinations

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

The goal is to write a function or program which takes a set of integer arrays and returns a set of all possible arrays which meet the following criteria:

- A valid array must contain at least one number from each of the input arrays.
- A valid array cannot contain more than one number from a single input array.
- A valid array cannot contain duplicate values.

**Additional rules:**

- Order of the output does not matter.
- Input/Output can be in any format you wish.
- If no valid arrays exist, the result should be an empty array or blank string.

**Examples:**

```
input:
[[1,2],
 [2,1,0],
 [0,3,1]]

output:
[[2,3],
 [1]]
```

```
input:
[[1,3,4,7],
 [1,2,5,6],
 [3,4,8],
 [8,9]]

output:
[[6,7,8],
 [5,7,8],
 [2,7,8],
 [4,6,9],
 [4,5,9],
 [2,4,9],
 [3,6,9],
 [3,5,9],
 [2,3,9],
 [1,8]]
```

```
input:
[[1,2,3],
 [2,3,4],
 [1,4]]

output:
[]
```

Comment: Related: [Helping the farmer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17096/helping-the-farmer)

Comment: Some explanation of what do you mean with 'overlap array'? Or a link...

Comment: @edc65 I've removed the term from the question to avoid confusion. They're just arrays.

Comment: @edc65, it's exact set cover with some of the input implicit. So the input sets are the elements to cover, and for each element of their union there is a set consisting of those input sets which contain that element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 36 characters

```
:I[[]]\{{{|$}+1$/}%|}/{I{1$&,(},!*},
```

Input/output is standard GolfScript arrays, see in [this example](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=W1sxIDMgNCA3XSBbMSAyIDUgNl0gWzMgNCA4XSBbOCA5XV0KCjpJW1tdXVx7e3t8JH0rMSQvfSV8fS97SXsxJCYsKH0sISp9LAoKcA%3D%3D&run=true).

```
:I              # save input to variable I

# part 1: generate all possible sets with zero or one numbers from each array
# (zero or one is one char shorter than exactly one which would work also)
[[]]\           # push the set with an empty set
{               # iterate over all input sets
  {             #   iterate over the numbers in the current set
    {|$}+1$/    #     add this number to any set in the result
  }%
  |             #   join with the result set
}/

# part 2: filter for valid sets (i.e. exactly one number from each array)
{               # start of filter block
  I{            #   filter the input array of sets
    1$&         #     calculate overlap of the current set with the input set
    ,(          #     remove if length is equal to one
  },
  !             #   is the list empty? (i.e. all input matched the filter criterion)
  *             #   get rid of the second item on the stack
},              # end of filter block
```

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, 35 bytes

```
q~:Q{m*{(+$_&}%}*_&{Q{1$&,(},,*!},p
```

Input is a list of list like:

```
[[1 3 4 7] 
 [1 2 5 6] 
 [3 4 8] 
 [8 9]]
```

and output is the list of unique lists that match all conditions, like for above input,

```
[[1 8] [2 3 9] [3 5 9] [3 6 9] [2 4 9] [4 5 9] [4 6 9] [2 7 8] [5 7 8] [6 7 8]]
```

How it works:

```
q~:Q                                 "Evaluate the input and store it in Q";
    {          }*                    "Run this block for each adjacent pair in the array";
     m*                              "Calculate Cartesian product of the pair";
       {     }%                      "Map each cartesian product with the code block";
        (+$                          "Flatten the array and sort it";
           _&                        "Make the array unique";
                 _&                  "Only take unique cartesian products";
                   {            },   "Filter the cartesian products based on the code block";
                    Q{     },        "Put Q on stack and run it through this filter";
                      1$&            "Take ∩ of the input array with the cartesian product";
                         ,(          "Check that length of the ∩ should be greater than 1";
                             ,*!     "Now we have all the lists from the input list of list"
                                     "which matched more than 1 element from this cartesian"
                                     "product. So if this list is non empty, discard this"
                                     "cartesian product";
                                  p  "Print the filtered out valid unique arrays";
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, <s>135</s> <s>84</s> 72 bytes

```
f=Cases[Union/@Tuples@#,l_/;!MemberQ[#,k_/;Length@Intersection[k,l]>1]]&
```

Less golf:

```
f = Cases[
   Union /@ Tuples@#,
   l_ /; ! MemberQ[#, k_ /; Length@Intersection[k, l] > 1]
] &
```

This defines a function `f` that expects the input as a plain Mathematica list of lists, e.g.

```
f[{{1, 2}, {2, 1, 0}, {0, 3, 1}}]
```

Basically, I'm creating a list of all lists that fulfil conditions 1 and 3, and then I'm filtering out those that violate conditions 2. <s>There might be a shortcut for one of the two, which I'll have to think about in more depth tomorrow.</s> Found that shortcut!

Answer (score 2):

## ruby, <del>143</del> 114

Now shorter thanks to @Ventero.

```ruby
h={};i=eval$*[0];v=i.flatten.uniq
loop{h[a=v.sample(1+rand(v.size)).sort]||=h[a]||i.any?{|o|(o&a).size!=1}?1:p(a)}
```

Usage:

```ruby
ruby uniq_arr.rb '[[1,3,4,7],[1,2,5,6],[3,4,8],[8,9]]'
[2, 3, 9]
[6, 7, 8]
[3, 5, 9]
[1, 8]
[2, 7, 8]
[4, 6, 9]
[5, 7, 8]
[2, 4, 9]
[3, 6, 9]
[4, 5, 9]
```

Making it stop (eventually) is easy, but requires some code. It stops one h contains 2**l-1 elements, l being the number of unique elements in i, i.flatten.uniq.size

http://ideone.com/zTlXZw

Comment: Some general improvements: `$*` is short for ARGV and allows dropping the whitespace after `eval`, `loop{...}` is a shorter infinite loop, `rand` is the same as `Random.rand` and `p` is a shorter way than `$_` to get `nil` (the function does nothing and returns `nil` if called without arguments). Also, I think your `reduce` can be replaced with `i.any?{|o|(o&a).size!=1}`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Ruby — <s>80</s> 73 characters

@Howard knocks off 7 characters:

```
f=->a{a[0].product(*a).map(&:uniq).uniq.select{|l|a.all?{|x|(l&x).one?}}}
```

Some sample input:

```
a = [[1, 2], [2, 1, 0], [0, 3, 1]]
b = [[1,3,4,7], [1,2,5,6], [3,4,8], [8,9]]
c = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [1,4]]
d = [[]]
e = [[1,2]]
```

Output:

```
f[a] # => [[1], [2, 3]]
f[b] # => [[1, 8], [3, 2, 9], [3, 5, 9], [3, 6, 9], [4, 2, 9], [4, 5, 9], [4, 6, 9], [7, 2, 8], [7, 5, 8], [7, 6, 8]]
f[c] # => []
f[d] # => []
f[e] # => [[1], [2]]
```

#### Haskell — 90 characters

I'm just learning Haskell, so I imagine this can be vastly improved. Same basic strategy as my Ruby solution.

```
import Data.List
f a=[l|l<-nub.map nub$sequence a,all(\x->length x==1)(map(intersect l)a)]
```

Comment: I think you can also use the shorter version `.product(*a)` since the invalid solutions are filtered afterwards anyways.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 157 characters

This is a straightforward brute-force implementation.

```python
from itertools import*
a=input()
v=set(chain(*a))
print[x for x in chain(*[combinations(v,r)for r in range(len(v))])if all(1==len(set(x)&set(y))for y in a)]
```